# Unity / How can i prevent my model from blinking when it doesnt have normals?

Tags: unity, lighting, models, fbx

Somehow the light which is shining on a moving model is making it "blink" (its like getting very dark and then very lit again.

The model has no normals. (unity import settings: normals: none)

Is there a way to prevent the blinking?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Maybe a screenshot/gif of the problem?

Comment: Hmm... a lit object with no normals is an odd combination. How would you like the object to respond to light instead, if the surfaces have no facing direction to compute the brightness of the light bouncing off of them?

Comment: I would like it to stay with the same brightness. 
The object is imported from another program and it has broken normals.
Letting unity compute normals doesnt work.